# Resizing JLabel smaller than its icon?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm using a JPanel containing a JLabel with an icon. I'm using a ComponentAdapter on the JLabel to request a correctly sized thumbnail from the controller (using MVC pattern) when the JLabel is resized. This works fine when the JLabel is resized to be bigger than before, so then it's filled with an ImageIcon the size of the JLabel. However, when resizing the window to be smaller, it simply doesn't resize the JLabel at all (because of the icon's size, I'm assuming).

Is there possibly some layout manager or setting to make the JLabel disregard its content (the ImageIcon) and resize itself anyways? I mean, it can truncate text, so it ought to be able to just show part of the image when resized smaller.

Comment: have you played with `JLabel.setMinimumSize()` ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: @Bala R -1 for advertizing the usage one of the setXXSize ;-)

Comment: icon size has no special weight - a LayoutManager truncating the text is already disrespecting the component's min, should cut an icon as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try experimenting with `setPreferredSize()` and `setMinimumSize()` to ensure the `JLabel` is allowing itself to shrink to the required size.  You also need to double-check what kind of `LayoutManager` you are using and what constraints, if any, you use when adding your component to the panel.  Try a different layout manager if you can.  If none of that works, you *will* need to provide some example code.

Comment: -1 for promoting the use of any of the setXXSize. Which not even would help here - the first part of the answer is simply wrong. Wild guesses rarely help ;-)

Comment: Fine, whatever. Pardon me for suggesting something that may or may not work for the OP when they didn't provide an example program.  And until they do, you have no proof that it wouldn't work.  If the component was a subclass of `JLabel` with a bad implementation of `setXXSize` then it could indeed be the problem.

Comment: we are talking about JLabel - it's implementation of min/pref size is well-known, no need to experiment nor guess, simply look it up.

Comment: This seemed to be the problem. The weird thing is that the minimum size of the JLabel was set to 0x0 when it was created, but calling setMinimumSize() with 0x0 after setting the icon solved it.

Comment: Wow... I'm really surprised that actually had an effect, especially when setting it to the same value as before. Was there anything else you changed at the same time?  It could just be that calling `setMinimumSize()` triggered a revalidation of the layout, so a call to `revalidate()` might have the same effect.